# How can I create a new dataframe in groupby method? Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe like this

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| One | 100 |
| Two | 200 |
| Three | 300 |
| Two | 201 |
| Two | 202 |
| One | 101 |

I need to groupby this table by Name and create a new dataframe with unique names in columns and values from Value column like this

| One | Two | Three |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 200 | 300 |
| 101 | 201 | NaN |
| NaN | 202 | NaN |

I tried to .agg this data with lambda, but had no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `assign` then `pivot` with `cumcount`

```
out = df.assign(key=df.groupby('Name').cumcount()).pivot('key','Name','Value')
Out[263]: 
Name    One  Three    Two
key                      
0     100.0  300.0  200.0
1     101.0    NaN  201.0
2       NaN    NaN  202.0
```